# Change box colors on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Okay so lets say you have box A, B, and C, I am trying to make it so that whenever box A is hovered over, A, B, and C change to green, when box B is hovered, they all change to green, and when C is hovered, they all change to green. Is this possible only using CSS or will I have to use javascript to do this?

Comment: Hi you will need to use JavaScript. I say you use jQuery and that is very easy to do as well. I do not think you can do it using css alone.

Comment: @HelloUniverse CSS only is possible, but I agree 100% that js is easier to code, scale, and maintain.

Comment: There are a multitude of ways to do this with CSS and javascript. It is your duty to find those solutions by searching Stack Overflow or the internet first. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Comment: Oh I misread. I thought u said hovering over a, causes b and c only to go green...

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this with CSS is to trigger based on hovering over the parent container but limit the pointer-events to the child elements.

```css
.box {
padding: 40px;
display: inline-block;
margin: 20px;
background: grey;
transition: background .2s;
pointer-events: all;
}

.container {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container:hover .box {
  background: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wish I can vote up twice. One for providing the right answer, the other for using chartreuse color.

Answer (score 0):

You may use JQuery hover event to achieve that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#A").hover(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color", "green");
     $("#B").css("background-color", "green");
     $("#C").css("background-color", "green");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");//original colour
     $("#B").css("background-color", "pink");
     $("#C").css("background-color", "pink");
});
$("#B").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");       
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");//original colour
});
$("#C").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");       
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");//original colour
});
```

});

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dLceh5Lw/

Answer (score 0):

Check this !!! it works fine :)

**put this in html page**

```
<div class="box-panel">
  <div class="box a"></div>
  <div class="box b"></div>
  <div class="box c"></div>
</div>
```

**put this within head tag in header**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .box-panel { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
  .box { width: 31.33%; float: left; margin: 0 1%; height: 250px; background-color: #ccc; }
  .box.a {  }
  .box.b {  }
  .box.c {  }
</style>
```

**put this within body tag after jquery link**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.a').hover(function(){
      $('.a, .b, .c').css('background-color', 'green');
  });
  $('.b').hover(function(){
      $('.a, .b, .c').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
  $('.c').hover(function(){
      $('.a, .b, .c').css('background-color', 'blue');
  });
```

Cheers !!!